# Convert byte array to ushort array in C# .Net Microframework

Tags: c#, .net-micro-framework

I need to convert a byte array to a UInt16 (ushort) array. I am able to do so from a byte array to a UInt32 array.

I already looked at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104599/convert-byte-array-to-short-array-in-c-sharp). But I cannot use BitConverter or the solution given in the referenced question.

I also referred to these questions as well:
[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210373/why-do-shift-operations-always-result-in-a-signed-int-when-operand-is-32-bits) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798666/cannot-implicity-convert-type-int-to-ushort-already-explicity-cast).

This is what I have tried so far.

```
for (uint objIndex = 0; objIndex < data.Length; ++objIndex)
{
   data[objIndex] = (Convert.ToUInt16(byteArray[objIndex * sizeof(UInt16) + 0].ToString()) << 8) 
                               + byteArray[objIndex * sizeof(UInt16) + 1]; 
   // Error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'ushort'. An explicit conversion exists.

   data[objIndex] = ((ushort)(byteArray[objIndex * sizeof(UInt16) + 0]) << 8)
                               + byteArray[objIndex + 1]; 
   // Error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'ushort'. An explicit conversion exists.
}
```

Please let me know what is missing here.

EDIT:
I was able to fix it after casting each of the number to an ushort as shown below.

```
for (ushort objIndex = 0; objIndex < data.Length; ++objIndex)
{
     ushort length = sizeof(UInt16);
     data[objIndex] = (ushort)( (ushort)(byteArray[objIndex * length] << (ushort)8) +
                                                 byteArray[objIndex + 1] );
}
```

Comment: Did you try the casts suggested by the compiler? ie: `data[objIndex] = (ushort) (((ushort)(byteArray[objIndex * sizeof(UInt16) + 0]) << 8)
                               + byteArray[objIndex + 1]; )`

Comment: Instead of editing your question, please post the solution as an aswer.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and did not work. But I was able to make the compiler error go away. Now I have to test if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it turned out to be a very simple fix (feeling silly right now). I was able to make the compiler error go away after casting each of the numbers I use to an ushort as shown below.

```
for (ushort objIndex = 0; objIndex < data.Length; ++objIndex)
{
    ushort length = sizeof(UInt16);
    data[objIndex] = (ushort)( (ushort)(byteArray[objIndex * length] << (ushort)8) +
                                             byteArray[objIndex + 1] );
}
```

Or this.

```
for (ushort objIndex = 0; objIndex < data.Length; ++objIndex)
{
    data[objIndex] = (ushort)((byteArray[objIndex * sizeof(UInt16)] << 8) +
                                                 byteArray[objIndex + 1] );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Check out [Buffer.BlockCopy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You can have the contents (`byte[]`) be dumped into a different format (`UInt16[]`).

Example:

```
var input = byte[1024];
var output = ushort[1024 / 2]; // every ushort is 2 bytes

Buffer.BlockCopy(input, 0, output, 0, 1024);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't have Buffer.BlockCopy() (though I added the mscorlib.dll). I get the message "Name Buffer does not exist in the current context".